# How to restart nginx on webfaction?

Tags: nginx, webfaction

I followed this post to install nginx and use it to serve another django app on webfaction- http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/install-nginx-webfaction/ 
I had started nginx using sbin/nginx as mentioned in the post. I closed that ssh session, so server kept running. I now want to restart and to my utter frustration can't figure out how. Furthermore, I can't see any relevant logs, I checked /home/logs/user and /home/logs/frontend and nginx/logs and there are older files in there but nothing that seems continuously updating (my website is running and some actions are not working and I get 'page unavailable' error but none of these logs show anything. I have tried ps -ef | grep nginx to figure out nginx pid and restart but when I try to kill one of the nginx processes, it says permission denied.

sbin/nginx stop or start or restart doesn't work. It must be sounding pretty silly but have tried for hours now, would appreciate any help.

Also, tried the following-

```
[xxx@xxx nginx]$ sbin/nginx -s quit 
nginx: [error] open() "/home/xxx/webapps/nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory) 
[xxx@xxx nginx]$ sbin/nginx -s reload 
nginx: [error] open() "/home/xxx/webapps/nginx/logs/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: never mind, my app was running through gunicorn and not using nginx

Answer (score 3):

I just do

```
$ cd ~/weapps/my-app-name
$ ./bin/restart
```

I also have this as a step in my capistrano (or mina) deployment scripts.

Comment: I choose this, clean and straight :)

Answer (score 2):

Restart nginx service in webfaction servers

```
[xxx@xxx nginx]$ sbin/nginx -p /home/xxx/webapps/myapp/nginx/ -s reload
```

Comment: cd /home/xxx/webapps/redmine/nginx && sbin/nginx -p /home/xxx/webapps/redmine/nginx/ -s reload

Answer (score 0):

To restart nginx from any directory on webfaction:

```
ssh your_username.webfactional.com
$ $HOME/webapps/[app_name]/nginx/sbin/nginx -p $HOME/webapps/[app_name]/nginx/ -s reload
```